# Obter recurso do sistema dentro do arquivo Jar (getSystemResource)

Tags: java

Desenvolvi um projecto no qual preciso de aceder a alguns ficheiros de configuração e algumas imagens. Dentro do projecto tenho uma pasta (resources) na qual tenho todos estes recursos de que preciso.
O problema é o seguinte:
Depois do projecto finalizado criei um jar e dentro do mesmo encontra-se todo o codigo e a pasta resouces.

Fui tentar correr o programa numa directoria onde so tenho duas coisas:
1 pasta (lib) onde tenho outros jar de que preciso
1 .jar com o meu projecto

executei no command prompt a seguinte linha:
java -cp myProject.jar;lib/*; project.entry.point.App

e obtive o seguinte erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acho que o problema esta em descobrir a path de um ficheiro, estou a fazer:
`ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/CREATE_DB.sql");`
mas como pode ver ali na imagem no erro que da apos o nome do .jar esta o caracter '!' nao percebo o porquê

Alguma ideia de como resolver o problema?

Comment: Tente colocar a pasta `resources` no mesmo diretório que está o jar, e execute novamente e veja se o problema persiste.

Comment: Kyllopardiun obrigado pela resposta, sim antes de colocar a questão eu fiz isso e funcionou mas supostamente a pasta esta dentro do .jar devia de haver maneira de conseguir fazelo sem ter a pasta resouces na directoria corrente

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema similar e o neste caso recomendo que use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("")` para poder manipular sem problemas.

## Exemplo

stack.**Config.java:**

```
package stack;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Config {
    private String usuario;
    private String db;
    private String website;
    private String path;
    public void setConfigPorStream(boolean flag){
        try{
            InputStream is; 
           if(flag){
                 // stack.res/conf.txt
                 is =  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/conf.txt");
           }
           else{
                 //res/conf.txt
                 is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("res/conf.txt");
           }
            //O tamanho do arquivo provavelmente será o mesmo sempre
            // e por isso BufferedReader é desnecessário.
           byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            is.read(b);
            String config = new String(b,"UTF-8");
            this.db = parseConfig(config, "dbUrl");
            this.website = parseConfig(config, "website");
            this.usuario = parseConfig(config, "usuario");
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setConfig_PastadoJar(boolean flag) {
        URL arquivo;
        if(flag)
            arquivo = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/conf.txt");
        else{
            arquivo = this.getClass().getResource("res/conf.txt");
        }        
        FileInputStream fis  = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(arquivo.getFile());
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            fis.read(b);
            String config = new String(b,"UTF-8");
            this.db = parseConfig(config, "dbUrl");
            this.website = parseConfig(config, "website");
            this.usuario = parseConfig(config, "usuario");
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public String getUsuario(){
            return this.usuario;
        }
        public String getDB(){
            return this.db;
        }
        public String getWebsite(){
            return this.website;
        }
    public static String parseConfig(String linha,String campo){
        linha = linha.replaceAll("\"","");
        int indice = linha.indexOf(campo) + 3 + campo.length();
        int ultimo_char = linha.indexOf(",", indice)!=-1?linha.indexOf(",", indice):linha.indexOf("}", indice);
        return linha.substring(indice,ultimo_char);
    }
}
```

stack.**StackOverflow**

```
package stack;
public class StackOverflow{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Config conf = new Config();
            System.out.println("-----------------------\n\tPasta onde está o jar\n-----------------------\n");
            conf.setConfig_PastadoJar(true);
            printConfig(conf);
            System.out.println("");
            conf.setConfig_PastadoJar(false);
            printConfig(conf);
            System.out.println("-----------------------\n\tDentro do jar\n-----------------------\n");
            conf.setConfigPorStream(false);
            System.out.println("StackOverflow.jar\\!res\\conf.txt");
            printConfig(conf);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("StackOverflow.jar\\!stack\\res\\conf.txt");
            conf.setConfigPorStream(true);
            printConfig(conf);
        }
        public static void printConfig(Config c){
            System.out.println("Usuario: " + c.getUsuario());
            System.out.println("DB: " + c.getDB());
            System.out.println("Website: " + c.getWebsite());
        }
        


}
```

res.**conf.txt**  && res.stack.**conf.txt**

```
{eg{usuario = "dbAdmin", dbUrl = "http://db.pt.stackoverflow.com", website = "pt.StackOverflow"}}
```

Note que neste exemplo não terá erros ao rodar em uma IDE (Netbeans/Eclipse) mas as duas primeiras configurações não rodar-se-ão diretamente se iniciar somente o Jar i.e.

```
java -jar StackOverflow.jar
```

Caso queira baixar o projeto o mesmo se encontra no [GitHub](https://github.com/kyllopardiun/StackOverflow/tree/master/Respostas/StackOverflow22127)